# Incorrect DateTime returned using LinqToTwitter?

Tags: twitter, linq-to-twitter

I'm returning tweets from `LinqToTwitter` using `TwitterContext.Status`.

however I've noticed that the `CreatedAt` property value returned for each tweet not the same as if I compare the `CreatedAt` to the representation displayed on **twitter.com** for the actual tweet.

The minutes part is obviously the same, however it looks like the user's **timezone offset** is not being applied to this value returned.  Therefore the result maybe like +8 hours off.

Is this what should be expected from the result set?, or just a bug?

If we have to apply an offset, how would I go about retrieving this to apply to all tweets returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CreatedAt, via the API, is a UTC time. The twitter.com, Web site, translates the date into your local time.

Comment: Hi Joe, Yes its UTC.  I've looked further at this and the correct time is shown on my iPhone and Windows Phone, however on the desktop its showing a time that is a number of hours off (-8 hours) despite my local machine being set to timezone +1 hour.  I guess the Twitter website isn't picking something up from the desktop browser correctly.

Comment: Curious, where are you located?

Comment: Europe.  Timezone in control panel set to +1 also.  IE and Google Chrome showing the -8 offset.  I checked also on Twitter and that setting for the user is +1 also, not that it should matter.  LinqToTwitter is working perfectly as far as I can see though, so I was thinking it maybe an OS issue.  However, I've just tested on a clean build Windows 7 and Windows 8.1, and its the same for some reason.  I will try with another Twitter account at some point as everything is starting to point that way but at the moment its not too important as I just need a date shown for testing :-)